# Augeas in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, configuration

I'm trying to use augtool in shell script ex:

```
#!/bin/bash

augtool <<-EOF
print /augeas/load
EOF
```

However if I execute this script, the script will run indefinitely with no output and the CPU usage is 100% via top cmd.

the command can be run successfully using

```
$augtool
$print /augeas/load
/augeas/load/Webmin/excl[4] = "/*.dpkg-bak"
/augeas/load/Webmin/excl[5] = "/*.dpkg-new"
/augeas/load/Webmin/excl[6] = "/*.dpkg-old"
/augeas/load/Webmin/excl[7] = "/*.rpmsave"
/augeas/load/Webmin/excl[8] = "/*.rpmnew"
/augeas/load/Webmin/excl[9] = "/*~"
... lots of output...
augtool> quit
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2 and the version of augtool is 0.10.0.

My question is: how to use augtool in shell script?

---

[edited]

I execute the strace command and get the following error:

```
lstat64("/augeas/load/", 0xbfc637d8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

and then it keeps looping and showing:

```
write(2, "\7", 1)                 = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0
read(0, "", 1)                    = 0
```

However if I execute this script with root, it runs successfully

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce your problem -- when I run your first script, it completes in less than a second.

Comment: You may run your script through strace in oder to see what's happening: `strace -o script.strace -f /path/to/script`

Comment: Why do you use the `-` in front of the first `EOF`, in `<<-EOF`?

Answer (score 2):

Like @Flup, I can't reproduce your issue.

Also note that you can actually also use `augtool` as an interpreter, too:

```
#!/usr/bin/augtool -f
print /augeas/load
```

Combining this with the `-s` (`--autosave`) flag if you want to make modification without explicitely calling `save` at the end of your script.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you explicitly quit from within the commands to augtool?

```
#!/bin/bash

augtool <<-EOF
print /augeas/load
quit
EOF
```